# How to apply convolution on the last three dimensions of a 5D tensor using the Conv2D in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

Usually the input tensor of the `Conv2D` in Keras is a 4D tensor with the dimension `batch_size * n * n * channel_size`. Now I have a 5D tensor with the dimension `batch_size * N * n * n * channel_size` and I want to apply the 2D convolutional layer for the last three dimensions for each i in `N`. For example, if the kernel size is 1, then I expect that the output will have the dimension `batch_size * N * n * n * 1`.

Anyone knows some easy ways to implement it with Keras?

For example, for the fully-connected layer Keras can do it automatically. If the input has the shape `batch_size * N * n`, then the Dense layer in Keras will set a FC layer for each i in `N`. Hence we will get the output with `batch_size * N * m`, if we set `Dense(m)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`TimeDistributed`](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) layer wrapper to apply the same convolution layer on all the images in the 5D tensor. For example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(5, (3,3), padding='same'), input_shape=(10, 100, 100, 3)))

model.summary()
```

Model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 10, 100, 100, 5)   140       
=================================================================
Total params: 140
Trainable params: 140
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Very quick answer! I will try that at once :)

Comment: It actually works but not exactly in a way that I expected. It seems that the weights are the same for every temporal parameter i in N. However, I wanted to set different weights for each i.

Comment: @Z.Ye Of course and I mentioned that in my answer. Further, that's also the case for the `Dense` layer example you provided, i.e. the weights are fixed. If you want different weights and the `N` is known, you can easily write a for loop to do that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The Dense layer also did what you described. Then I will try loop.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can not upvote your answer. I tried the for loop a bit, but it didn't not work perfectly. I posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093755/what-does-the-concatenate-layer-in-keras-make-the-training-very-slow  . Could you give me a hint? Thank you very much.